# Error Image::Compare (jpg files)

Tags: image, perl, compare, jpeg

I'm trying to use [`Image::Compare`](http://metacpan.org/pod/Image::Compare) in perl to compare two images based on the colors used in the images. Here is the code i'm using:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Image::Compare;
my ($cmp) = Image::Compare->new();
$cmp->set_image1(
    img  => "$ARGV[0]",
    type => 'jpg',
);
$cmp->set_image2(
    img  => "$ARGV[1]",
    type => 'jpg',
);
$cmp->set_method(
    method => &Image::Compare::THRESHOLD,
    args   => 70,
);

if ( $cmp->compare() ) {
    print "same \n";
} else {
    print "not same\n";
}
```

When run it, it gave the error:

> `Unable to read image data from file 'test_002.jpg': 'format 'jpg' not
>   supported - formats bmp, ico, pnm, raw, sgi, tga available for reading
>   - Can't locate Imager/File/JPG.pm or Imager/File/JPGReader.pm' at /usr/local/share/perl/5.18.2/Image/Compare.pm line 162.`

I've tried to install `Imager::File::JPEG`, but also gave me errors:

> `$ cpan install Imager::File::JPEG Reading '/home/b0y/.cpan/Metadata'
>
>   Database was generated on Sat, 18 Oct 2014 07:05:12 GMT Running
>   install for module 'Imager::File::JPEG' Running make for
>   T/TO/TONYC/Imager-File-JPEG-0.88.tar.gz Checksum for
>   /home/b0y/.cpan/sources/authors/id/T/TO/TONYC/Imager-File-JPEG-0.88.tar.gz
>   ok`
>
> `CPAN.pm: Building T/TO/TONYC/Imager-File-JPEG-0.88.tar.gz`
>
> `JPEG: building independently JPEG: main: includes not found -
>   libraries found JPEG: Checking if the compiler can find them on its
>   own JPEG: Test code failed: Can't link/include 'jpeglib.h', 'jpeg' OS
>   unsupported: JPEG libraries or headers not found Warning: No success
>   on command[/usr/bin/perl Makefile.PL INSTALLDIRS=site]
>
>   TONYC/Imager-File-JPEG-0.88.tar.gz   /usr/bin/perl Makefile.PL
>   INSTALLDIRS=site -- NOT OK Running make test   Make had some problems,
>   won't test Running make install   Make had some problems, won't
>   install Could not read metadata file. Falling back to other methods to
>   determine prerequisites`

Many thanks.

Comment: Do you have libjpeg installed? There are comprehensive installation instructions in [Imager::Install](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Imager/lib/Imager/Install.pod).

Answer (score 3):

You need to install "libjpeg-dev",

```
sudo apt-get install libjpeg-dev
```

Comment: It's allready installed:
`$ sudo apt-get install libjpeg-dev
[sudo] password for b0y: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libjpeg-dev is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 47 not upgraded.`

Answer (score 0):

For your error:

```
  "JPEG: building independently JPEG: main: includes not found -
  libraries found JPEG: Checking if the compiler can find them on its
  own JPEG: Test code failed: Can't link/include 'jpeglib.h', 'jpeg' OS
  unsupported: JPEG libraries or headers not found Warning: No success
  on command[/usr/bin/perl Makefile.PL INSTALLDIRS=site]"
```

Your header "jpeglib.h" ins't in your PATH, it means that your compiler can't find it. If you are using a Debian like OS you can follow the instructions below:

```
  echo "export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path to your lib/lib" >> ~/.bashrc
  echo "export C_INCLUDE_PATH="/path to your include/include" >> ~/.basrc
  $. ~/.basrc
  $cpan install Imager::File::JPEG
```

If doesn't work,

```
$cpan 
>look Imager::File::JPEG
$LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/path to your lib/lib" C_INCLUDE_PATH="/path to your include/include" perl Makefile.PL
$make test
$make install
$exit
```